# Can I add legacy html/js script into React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm pretty new to front end development, I have a react app and want to add in some older html code that was created previously. (This html code refers to multiple .js files). I need to do several things with my react data, then when I have done that, the user can select part of the results which should fire the existing html functionality.

To do this attempted the following:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "/address/of/file.html";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This errors out with the following message: *"Syntax error: unexpected token <"*. (< is the first character used in the .html file)

I have also tried refactoring the code itself but it is thousands of lines long.

Any ideas on how this can be done, or do I just need to add in each JS file separately, and do the html bit in the react component itself?

Comment: You are creating a script tag and putting html inside of it. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Tholle The html file contains several .js files & does the processing, but now that you mention it maybe I should be importing those .js files separately and doing the stuff from the html file myself? I know that doing is as mentioned above just runs the file so not sure how it would work getting them all in separately

Answer (score 1):

You can put include your react app inside your older html, you just have to call `ReactDOM.render` wherever you want your app to be

```html
<body>
  <!-- older html code -->
  <div id='appRoot'></div>
</body>
```

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

Make sure your older code (especially the js) does not interfere with React i.e. does not DOM manipulate anything that lies inside your `#appRoot`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an external script, you can't use the .html extension. However, you can use a .js file with the javascript of the page in it :

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "/address/of/file.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

And you will be able to use this js file for as many pages as you want.

The unexpected token "<" comes from the 
    `<!doctype html>`
 of your .html page